# How to convert a byte string with a unicode character to normal text in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following string in Python 3:

```
bytestring = b'Zeer ge\xc3\xafnteresseerd naar iemands verhalen luisteren.'
```

How do I get this to a string with normal characters? That is:

```
'Zeer geïnteresseerd naar iemands verhalen luisteren.'
```

I've already tried decoding it using:

```
bytestring.decode('utf-8)
```

But when I try to print that value to the console Python gives me the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xef' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Any help appreciated.

---

SOLUTION

I solved the problem by typing the following in the terminal:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

After that I was able to print the decoded bytestring to the console.

Comment: Please see [ask] and consult the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=byte%20decode#bytes.decode).

Comment: @Idlehands thanks for pointing out. I've edited the question. Does the current structure respect the guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are working with unicode rather than string. See if this helps. You decode using this custom function; first with UTF8 and then with Latin1 then encode to ascii.

```
def CustomDecode(mystring):
    '''Accepts string and tries decode with UTF8 first and then Latin1'''
    c=''.join(map(lambda x: chr(ord(x)),mystring))
    decval = None
    try:
        decval = c.decode('utf8')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        decval = c.decode('latin1')
    return decval


CustomDecode(mystring).encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Result:

```
'Zeer genteresseerd naar iemands verhalen luisteren.'
```

Comment: Doesn’t work for me, I get this error:

print(bytestring.decode("utf-8"))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xef' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Did not work either. I solved it using 'export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8'

Comment: nice. one. I am glad you solved it.Thanks Max for getting back